# Trying to insert data into a field using a subquery

Tags: php, mysql

I want to populate a field from my DB, using a subquery with timediff function...

it seems to me like it is a syntax error. so this is my code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO paros (tipo, descripcion, ho, hf, totaltiempo(select 
timediff(hf, ho) from paros)) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($tipo,$descripcion, $startTime, $endTime, 
$totaltiempo));
Database::disconnect();
```

And I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(select timediff(hf, ho) from paros)) values ('Paro no programado','Ajuste de pa' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\oeemoldeo\paros.php:43 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\oeemoldeo\paros.php(43): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown on line 43

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `select` returns only one record a an according `where` clause. Then use:

```
INSERT INTO paros (tipo, descripcion, ho, hf, totaltiempo) 
select ?, ?, ?, ?, timediff(hf, ho) from paros where ...
```

Comment: I just tried what you told me, now my code looks like this:

    $sql = "INSERT INTO paros (tipo, descripcion, ho, hf, totaltiempo) select ?, ?, 
    ?, ?, timediff(hf, ho) from paros where id = 1";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    THIS LINE: $q->execute(array($tipo,$descripcion, $startTime, $endTime, 
    $totaltiempo));
    Database::disconnect();

but shows this mistake on the selected line above with capital letters:

Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: Strange. It should not return this error. You you sure it is the same query the errors refers to? Does the `paros` table contain columns `hf` and `ho`?

Comment: Yeah the paros table contains ho and hf fields and the error message refers to the $q-> execute line

Comment: The error states that you provide not so many values as the query expects. Do you fill those 4 parameters or did you add a new one in your `where` clause?

Comment: No I didn’t add any other value with my where clause, I fill the other 4 fields inserting data from a form, I have the feeling that is showing that error for the last value, you know after the 4 question marks, but I’m now sure about it

Comment: But you are providing **5** values for only **4** `?`. See here: `execute(array($tipo,$descripcion, $startTime, $endTime, $totaltiempo))`